# Wordpress Importer - Menu item not imported in PHP Version 7.0.8

Tags: php, wordpress, import, menu

I am using WordPress Importer 0.6.1 to import xml data, but when I import XML via WordPress Importer plugin, it is importing only the main menu but not menu items. So can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below URL, this bug is already updated in wordpress importer plugin.

```
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/menu-not-imported-in-php-version-708/
```